# Remove PdfName.Rotate value without rotation

Tags: java, itext7

I have to combine multiple pages from several files into new one PDF. The page orientation of all the pages must be portrait.

After this work is done, I am using a couple of programs to reset the rotation to zero without really rotate the page.

I want to use itext to remove the rotation value.

Taked from itext examples, I've tried something like this:

```
    protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
        int n = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfPage page;
        PdfNumber rotate;
        for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
            page = pdfDoc.getPage(p);
            rotate = page.getPdfObject().getAsNumber(PdfName.Rotate);
            page.setRotation(0);
        pdfDoc.close();
    }
}
```

This:

```
PdfDictionary diccionario = page.getPdfObject();
diccionario.Remove(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Rotate);
```

And the function `CopyPagesTo` with the same result: The pages orientation has been altered.

Here there is an example file with 0, 90, 180 y 270 degrees.
**The goal is set rotate value of all pages to zero keeping portrait mode**:

https://filebin.ca/4vep0uuU1p2s/1.pdf

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception" uhm, that's not C#, it's Java. EDIT: Every line of code in this question is Java. Why is this tagged as C#?

Comment: What is the issue? If you remove a 90° or 270° page rotation, a portrait page becomes landscape by definition. If you want a portrait page, keep the rotation.

Comment: Please, open the example file. You will see 4 identical pages. But they have 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees.

Comment: *"You will see 4 identical pages. But they have 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees."* - Yes. And obviously by removing a 90° or 270° rotation value, you'll get landscape pages. If you want to counteract that, you'll have to considerably change the pages. You'll have to prefix the content stream with a transformation which is equivalent with the missing rotation. You'll have to adapt all applying page boxes, at least the media box. You'll have to adapt the positions (and other coordinate attributes) of all annotations; if they have appearances, you'll have to apply rotation to the. Unless they...

Comment: Unless they have the **NoRotate** flag set, in that case you'll have to relocate them. You'll have to adapt all destinations with coordinates. And surely some other tasks, too. ... *Are you sure you really need that page rotation entry to be 0? Probably it's easier to improve the process for which you want to do this to be able to operate with page rotation...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution using the `SetIgnorePageRotationForContent` function.

VB.NET example:

```vb
Dim srcPdf As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument = New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(srcFile))
Dim destPDF As New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(destFile))

For contador = 1 To srcPdf.GetNumberOfPages

    Dim srcPage = srcPdf.GetPage(contador)

    Dim rotacion As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfNumber = srcPage.GetPdfObject().GetAsNumber(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Rotate)


    If IsNothing(rotacion) OrElse rotacion.IntValue = 0 Then
        srcPdf.CopyPagesTo(contador, contador, destPDF)
        Continue For
    End If

    Dim destPage As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage = destPDF.AddNewPage(New iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize(srcPage.GetPageSizeWithRotation))

    If rotacion.IntValue = 180 Then
        destPage.GetPdfObject().Put(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Rotate, New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfNumber(180))
    Else
        destPage.GetPdfObject().Put(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Rotate, New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfNumber(rotacion.IntValue + 180))
    End If

    destPage.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(True)


    Dim canvas As New iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas(destPage)


    Dim pageCopy As iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject.PdfFormXObject = srcPage.CopyAsFormXObject(destPDF)
    canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0)

    destPage.GetPdfObject().Remove(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Rotate)

Next
destPDF.Close()
srcPdf.Close()
```